# Загрузить картинку с помощью opencv

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

У меня есть просчитанная нейросеть. Я хочу с помощью opencv брать кадры из видео, прогонять их через нейросеть и выводить результат.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\snow.mp4")
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    # Загружаем изображение
    img_path = frame
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(200, 200))

# Преобразуем изображением в массив numpy
x = image.img_to_array(img)

# Инвертируем и нормализуем изображение
x /= 255
x = np2.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
prediction = mod.predict(x)
prediction = np.argmax(prediction[0])
print(classes[prediction])

print(frame)
#print(gray)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

в итоге выходит ошибка

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\q\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2655     try:
-> 2656         fp.seek(0)
   2657     except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-b6889e26cf03> in <module>
      5     # Загружаем изображение
      6     img_path = frame
----> 7     img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(200, 200))
      8 
      9     # Преобразуем изображением в массив numpy

~\Anaconda3\envs\q\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    108         raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
    109                           'The use of `load_img` requires PIL.')
--> 110     img = pil_image.open(path)
    111     if color_mode == 'grayscale':
    112         if img.mode != 'L':

~\Anaconda3\envs\q\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2656         fp.seek(0)
   2657     except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):
-> 2658         fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
   2659         exclusive_fp = True
   2660 

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

как корректно взять кадр из видео?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

после строки:

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

в переменной `frame` **уже** находится 3D (если видео цветное) Numpy Array. Поэтому нет смысла пытаться открыть `frame` как файл с изображением.

Вместо этого измените размер картинки:

```
img = cv2.resize(frame, (200, 200))
```

Comment: а зачем в серый переводить?

Comment: @rowwwansl, исходя из вашего кода `target_size=(200, 200)` - вы пытаетесь прочитать картинку в градациях серого и преобразовать ее к размеру `(200, 200)`. Цветные картинки имеют третье измерение - цветовой канал

Comment: тоесть чтобы сделать цветной нужно в скобки через запятую 3 поставить? просто когда я пробовал в google colab он по умолчинию цветной был

Comment: @rowwwansl, по-моему можно оставить `(200, 200)`, но здесь все зависит от того что ожидает ваша модель. Если модель обучена на монохромных картинках - она не сможет работать с цветными. Но это уже тема для отдельного вопроса...

Comment: на цветных изображениях, мне получается нужно COLOR_BGR2GRAY на чтото поменять?